# Google ConversionTracking in IOS phonegap app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, google-analytics, conversion-tracking

I am trying to install the google conversion tracking SDK for ios.
https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/ios/#incorporate_the_sdk

I just updated an app to Xcode 7.2 and the app compability is ios 7.1.

Going through the steps in the guide from Google. Adding the sdk folder and adding this line (with correct ids) to the AppDelegate.m in "Classes-folder":

```
[ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID:@"MY_ID" label:@"MY_LABEL" value:@"MY_VALUE" isRepeatable:NO];
```

But Xcode fails with the error:
Use of **undeclered identifier 'ACTConversionReporter'**

I've been using hours but no luck, maby this is a problem with building with phonegap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to get it to work.

But ended up using a plugin which did the trick:

https://github.com/letrunghieu/google-app-conversion-tracker